# JQuery PHP & Contenteditible

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am having a problem updating a database field via jquery and php with contenteditible. The ajax.php file just takes my input from the form and updates the database when the user clicks away but for some reason I can never hit the $("td[contenteditable=true]").blur(function().  Is it because I am displaying the html from the js file?  If so how can I get the .blur() to run this way?

Here is a snip of my php.

```
 <div id="status"></div>
 <div class="row">
    <div id="html"></div>
 </div>
```

My js file

```
$(function(){
var message_status = $("#status");
$("td[contenteditable=true]").blur(function(){
    var field_userid = $(this).attr("id") ;
    var value = $(this).text() ;
    $.post('ajax.php' , field_userid + "=" + value, function(data){
        if(data != '')
            {
                message_status.show();
                message_status.text(data);
                //hide the message
                setTimeout(function(){message_status.hide()},3000);
            }
        });
    });
//snip
});

function updateTable() {
//snip
$.post("controller.php", payload, displayTable);
}    

function displayTable(data){
var obj_defect = $.parseJSON(data);
//snip
    html += '<thead><tbody>';
    for(i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {

        html +='<tr>';
        html +='<td width="10%">' + obj[i].row1 + '</td>';
        html +='<td width="10%">' + obj[i].row2 + '</td>';
        html +='<td width="10%">' + obj[i].row3 + '</td>';
        html +='<td width="10%">' + obj[i].row4 + '</td>';
        html +='<td id="row0:'+obj[i].id+'" contenteditable="true"> ' + obj[i].row5 + '</td>';
        html +='</tr>';
    }
    html += '</tbody></table>';
} else {
    html = '<h4>No results found</h4>';
}
}
$("#html").html(html);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your listener must run AFTER the element exists. You currently create the contenteditble td row after you receive the data from your post, which means when you go to assign a listener at page load there is no object in existence yet.

Something like this should work:

```
$.post("controller.php", payload, displayTable).done(function() {
  // now create listener on td[contenteditable=true]
});
```